# How To Track the Number Of Downloads installed from In-House Dist (Enterprise Account)

Tags: iphone

I am Having Enterprise account..I dist the app through this acc.

How can i track the number of installs through this acc . 
Is there anything like itunesconnect.apple.com which shows us the Number of downloads when we submit to appstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to track that out of the box. You will need to setup something like that yourself.

For example, you could send a tracking request bundled with the UDID of the device, store them in a database and count unique UDIDs for getting such value.